# Function in Watson conversation

Tags: json, latex, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I am successfully using Watson conversation Service. But now requirement is to put math Equation in Watson Response. How do I do that? Also I tried using an external Mathematics keyboard to type, but since my TTS service does not understand equations, I don’t get my desired response. Is there a way to use LaTex here? Also is there a way to put function in my JSON Watson Response.
Thanks so much
Eg:

[image]

Comment: This is more a rendering question. It might be better to ask on the TeX exchange.  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292348/user-utf-8-string-in-context

Comment: Thanks maybe i'll ask my question there.

Comment: Also @SimonO'Doherty your blog is really helpful. Keep going.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two questions here:

1. How to send an mathematical equation in a Watson Conversation Service response
2. How to synthesize a mathematical formula to text with the Watson Text to Speech service.

For #1, see my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/41489073/933879 - it's basically any text you want including JSON and HTML, and you can optionally convert/translate it before speaking or displaying it to your user.

For #2, you will need to write out the equation in words. So, instead of "f(x)", you'd need to send the TTS service the string "f of x", etc. (The service supports some customization, but I don't think it would work for this situation.)

If you use JSON for the response, you could include both versions - a HTML one for display and a "wordy" one for TTS. (Note that because the service already sends JSON back with a string response, you're going to end up with JSON-inside-of-JSON. Not ideal, but not the end of the world.)

To get started, it's going to be much simpler to do it this way and just write things twice. Your initial "translation" layer will decode the JSON, split those two up and e.g. display the math part as HTML and call the Text to Speech service with the wordy part.

You can see some example apps at https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=conversation&type=&language= - most of those convert the responses to HTML, so it would just be a simple jump from there to HTML + Audio.

Once you have it working smoothly with manual conversion from formulas to words, you can start working on a system to automate this. I don't have any experience here, but I have a feeling that it's more complex than it sounds. I'm not aware of any existing code to do this, so you're pretty much on your own at this point.

Here's a picture of what I mean when I say JSON for the html and wordy response:

[image: IBM Watson conversation tooling UI with JSON output]

And, here's an example of processing that with a translation layer:

```
// this is meant to run in a browser
// `WatsonSpeech` is from https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-javascript-sdk/releases
// `ttsToken` is an auth token you generate server-side, eg: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-javascript-sdk/blob/master/examples/tts-token.js
// `res` is the JSON Object returned from the Conversation service's send endpoint - http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/#send_message

function translationLayer(res) {
  var formula = JSON.parse(res.output.text[0]);
  $('#output').append(formula.html);
  WatsonSpeech.TextToSpeech.synthesize({
    text: formula.wordy,
    token: ttsToken
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Nathan, I did understand what we are doing here. Above in my original question I have included my LaTex script which i render using MathJax. Can you specifically help on how to do the above from within Dialog flow? I guess i can put my `<body>` part in my Dialog Flow. Is that right? Thanks so much for the reply.

Comment: I've never worked with MathJax or LaTex, but yea, you should be able to take the content from your <body> tag and put that into the Dialog flow.

Comment: Hi @Nathan, I did the point of the question (using an external mathematics keyboard) and displaying it on my interface. Now for point 2.. You suggested on putting up a "wordy" for TTS. Can you please advice me on how do I do it from my application client level? Also I too think translation layer would be helpful here. How do I go about that.

Comment: I expanded the answer a little bit more and clarified that you definitely want to start by just writing things out twice.

Comment: I understand the complexity of it when automated. But what i fail to understand is how do i put a wordy part? Do i create a new workspace at my conversation? or how do i do a translation layer which will split the math part and the wordy part for TTS in my application code?

Comment: You can update your existing workspace. 

Determining what to put into the wordy part is up to you, but it's basically "how would I say this formula out loud", and then convert all of the symbols into words. If you have a formula that you're not sure how to say out loud of a symbol that you're not sure what it's name is, ask on http://math.stackexchange.com/.

I added a screenshot where I created a JSON response with wordy and html parts, and then a simple JavaScript translation layer that parses the JSON, adds the HTML to the page, and uses our SDK to say the wordy part.